# Universal Image Loader inSampleSize option

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I'm using Uinversal Image Loader in my application, I need to load the images inSampleSize, how to do that?  I read this from the author

> Added DecodingType parameter for DisplayImageOptions

but I'm not figuring out to do, a snipped code would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DecodingType` was renamed to `ImageScaleType` long time ago.
`ImageScaleType` has next options:

- **NONE** (inSampleSize = 1)
- **IN_SAMPLE_POWER_OF_2** (inSampleSize = 1,2,4,8,16,...)
- **IN_SAMPLE_INT** (inSampleSize = 1,2,3,4,5,...)
- **EXACTLY** (bitmap will be scaled exactly for ImageView size)
- **EXACTLY_STRETCHED** (if image is smaller than ImageView then it will be stretched)

Comment: Thanks, it's exactly what I were looking for!